# How to upload and read large files line by line in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, npm

I am trying to upload a large file to Express and I am able to read the files object successfully using `express-fileupload` *middleware*, like below.

```js
{
  myfile: {
    name: 'somelargefile.txt',
    data: <Buffer /* details truncated */ ... 110075790 more bytes>,
    size: 110075840,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'text/plain',
    md5: '/* details truncated */',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
}
```

However, express might take up a **lot of memory** if I save the entire file into the files object. How can I read the file line by line, like using stream, from the request object?

Answer (score 0):

For large files, `readFileSync` can be inconvenient, as it loads the whole file in memory. A different synchronous approach is to iteratively call `readSync`, reading small bits of data at a time, and processing the lines as they come.

Eg:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = 'test.txt'

var fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'r');
var bufferSize = 1024;
var buffer = new Buffer(bufferSize);

var leftOver = '';
var read, line, idxStart, idx;
while ((read = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, bufferSize, null)) !== 0) {
  leftOver += buffer.toString('utf8', 0, read);
  idxStart = 0
  while ((idx = leftOver.indexOf("\n", idxStart)) !== -1) {
    line = leftOver.substring(idxStart, idx);
    console.log("one line read: " + line);
    idxStart = idx + 1;
  }
  leftOver = leftOver.substring(idxStart);
}
```